# how can I implement horizontal scrolling in all rows of a table in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am trying a implement horizontol scrolling in all the rows of tableview controller, but do not know how to go about it. Kindly help as I am quite new to iOS development.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you want to horizontal scroll contents of each cell? or you want to horizontal scroll all cells of table?

Comment: I want to scroll contents of each cell horizontally.

Comment: Then you have to add scrollview to each cell with horizontal scrolling.